# Populating select in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a quantity select option in a knockout table but I want to set a max limit on it based on the stock available.

Say I have the following values for an entry

```
ID = 1
stock = 8
```

I want to populate the quantity field with numbers 1-stock, in this case 1-8. Quantity will always be less than or equal to stock.

```
function ItemEntry(ID, stock, quantity) {
    var self = this;
    self.ID= ID;
    self.stock= stock;
    self.quantity = quantity;

}

// viewmodel
function EntryViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.itemNumbers = ko.observableArray([
        new ItemEntry("1", 8, QUANTITY HERE!) //initial starting values
    ]);

    self.removeItem = function(item) { self.itemNumbers.remove(item) }
}

//custom binding for dropdown outside of models
ko.bindingHandlers.quantityDropdown = {
        update: function(quantityDropdown, stock, EntryViewModel) {
            var quantity = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(stock());
            for(var i = 0; i < stock(); i++)
            {
               $(quantityDropdown).append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
            }
        }
    };

ko.applyBindings(new EntryViewModel());
```

Here's the HTML

```
  <table border="1">
  <thead><tr>
        <th>ID</th><th>Stock</th><th>Quantity</th><th></th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: itemNumbers">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: ID"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: stock"></td>
            <td><select data-bind="quantityDropdown: quantity"></select></td>
            <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeItem">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom binding outside of your view model code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.quantityDropdown = {

    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var quantity = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        for(var i = 1; i < quantity + 1; i++)
        {
            // Add each option element to the select here
            $(element).append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
        }
    }
};
```

Then change your binding to:

```
<td><select data-bind="quantityDropdown: stock"></select></td>
```

Comment: In the area you commented (within the loop), do I just push that value into the itemNumbers array? I don't understand what you mean. Also, does this go in the viewmodel section?

Comment: No, create a LI element and add it to the element passed through to the method. I'll update the answer with an example using jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, just getting back into the swing of things after an illness, brain still not up to speed yet! Ignore the LI, I meant OPTION! Updated my answer, it should make sense now. :)

Comment: I see what you did and it makes sense, but I can't seem to get it to work. I updated my code above. Is this supposed to go in the viewModel? I placed it in ItemEntry (the model I guess?). Is there an issue with the way I'm referencing stock. I figured it would be self.stock but my IDE (komodo) was giving me an error when I referenced it like that.

Comment: Ah, you probably need to make quantity an observable for it to work, thinking about it. Can you debug it, and see what valueAccessor is in that method? I'm just wondering whether it is the actual quantity, so you can therefore just reference it without using the brackets, or if it is undefined, in which case you need to make quantity an observable in your child view model.

Comment: I've added code from the example in the documentation using unwrap to get the value out of valueAccessor, regardless of whether it is an observable or not. See if that works.

Comment: Still nothing. I have a feeling I'm either incorrectly referencing something or I've placed it in the wrong section. I updated my code above entirely to reflect what I currently have.

Comment: Ah, right, yes, sorry, I didn't make it explicit that the binding handler sits outside your view models entirely.

Comment: I updated my code above. Am I not referencing something correctly? Should I be referencing ItemEntry or EntryViewModel? The only place where "stock" is specifically referenced is ItemEntry, not the ViewMod

Comment: Nothing jumps out as incorrect. What is actually going wrong? Is nothing being displayed? What happens when you put a break point in the update method of the binding handler? Is it hit, and what are the values in it?

Comment: The select list appears but it's empty. I could be way off, but to me it seems as if stock isn't being referenced properly. Stock is defined in the ItemEntry model but the custom binding references the EntryViewModel which does not define stock. The EntryViewModel only inserts a value into the position for stock of the itemNumbers array

Comment: The handler is referencing the value that you pass into it in the data-bind, in this case it's the quantity on each object in itemNumbers. Oh, sorry, you want it to be bound to stock rather than quantity then?

Comment: That was it! I changed the table row for data-ind to inventory rather than quantity. Thanks!